# LWJGL Key issue

Tags: java, keyboard, key, lwjgl

I am making a class in my game engine were it will check for key inputs and I have all the keys set up in an `enum` where the I will select the ordinal `int` value from the list when I need it and it looks like it works, no warnings no errors and it starts however, when I try to check for the input in my main it crashes for some reason. Could someone please help me.

From my main class:

```
private void OnGameUpdate()
{
    KeyManager key = new KeyManager();

    if(key.KeyPressed(Keys.KEY_W))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, it works!", "Test", JFrame.ERROR);
    }
}
```

Key Manager class:

```
public class KeyManager 
{
    private int CurrentKey;

    public enum Keys
    {
        KEY_0,
        KEY_1,
        KEY_2,
        //[...]all the other keys...
        KEY_Y,
        KEY_YEN,
        KEY_Z,
        KEYBOARD_SIZE
    }

    public boolean KeyPressed(Keys key)
    {
        this.CurrentKey = key.ordinal();
        return Keyboard.isKeyDown(CurrentKey);
    }

}
```

Comment: show us the Keyboard class! it might help, how you check if currentKey is down - don't post all keys you have...

Comment: I have, it's below it.

Comment: LWJGL have an import that has Keyboard support import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

Comment: oh yes, now i see... sorry, i was to fast...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when calling

```
Keyboard.isKeyDown(CurrentKey);
```

you're using the enum CurrentKey - but when you use enum.ordinal() you don't get the int-value that represents the key...

you must map your keys to the enum, because when you run your code:

```
Keys.KEY_0.ordinal() = 0; //what comes out
```

but you want

```
Keys.Key_0.ordinal() = 11; //what would be expected
```

one way to do this is to create a numbered enum:

```
public enum Keys
{
    KEY_0 (11),
    KEY_1 (2),
    //and so on

    KEY_xy(4711);

    int id;
    Keys(int id){
        this.id = id
    }

    @override
    int ordinal(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

i must confess i'm writing that enum from out of my head, so maybe there are minor typing errors on it...

Comment: copmare your Keys.ordinal with the definition from http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/constant-values.html#org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard

Comment: Ok I get what you mean, i'll combine the two. Thank you Martin Frank.